# Does there exist a way within the context of MAAS to specify which disk shows up as sda when provisioning nodes with multiple disks?

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive, maas

I am looking for a method by which I can specify the disk elected to be sda on enlisted MAAS nodes with multiple disks when they undergo commissioning, OR a method to specify which disk of those found in discovery data after commissioning gets the OS installed to upon deployment.

Preface:

I am using MAAS to manage servers which have > 1 disk, the disks are connected to a jbod controller, some are ssd, some are hhd.  I have been able to identify the order in which the controller recognizes the bays by process of elimination, which IS consistent across reboots per controller, but not consistent across different servers (the bays are recognized in a different order on each different card on each different server). I would like to load up my servers with drives and use MAAS to elect the desired drive on which to install the OSin the case disks are dissimilar.

Steps Taken:

I have looked into editing the preseed but I'm not sure where to start....

Any advice on the matter from someone with a little MAAS know how would be greatly 
appreciated!

Update/Workaround:

As a workaround I am physically unseating all disks other than the disk I wish MAAS to see as sda, then commissioning the node, then properly seating the other drives before I use maas to start the node.

Comment: Can you share more details on what you mean by unseating? And how did you configure that?